# How to assign value in query which running a Hive query

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Im trying to run a query where I need to group by a modified value and select the same value. I dont want to duplicate the UDF calls in both places. Is there a way to retain the value for the UDF once applied?

The query looks like this conceptually:
SELECT concat(day(datetimeVal), ': ', hour(datetimeVal),
.
.
.

FROM table
GROUP BY 
concat(day(datetimeVal), ': ', hour(datetimeVal)

I dont want to do "concat(day(datetimeVal), ': ', hour(datetimeVal)" two times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Hive you do need to the "concat(day(datetimeVal), ': ', hour(datetimeVal)"  twice unless you made a secondary table such that

```
Select day_hour from(Select concat(day(datetimeVal),':',hour(datetimeVal) as day_hour, 
* from table) GROUP BY day_hour;
```

Otherwise Hive will get confused and not even run unfortunately.